# Material UI browser compatibility

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have a reactjs application that is using v3.9.0 of material Ui , i want to know which version of different browser it supports.
I searched for it a lot on internet but didn't find any resources for it,
I want to know is there a way by which i can get versions of browser that supports material ui 3.9.0
Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Information about the material ui browser compatibility can be found here. For Version 5: - https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/supported-platforms/ For Version 4: - https://v4.mui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/ For Version 3: - https://v3.mui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/